# 'System.Collections.Stack' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

Tags: c#, stack, ienumerable, breadth-first-search

```
public class BreadthFirstDirectedPaths
{
    private static readonly Int32 INFINITY = Int32.MaxValue;
    private Boolean[] _marked;  //keep track of whether vertex v is reachable from s
    private int[] _edgeTo;      //keep track of the last edge on path s to v
    private int[] _distTo;      //keep track of length of shortest s->v path

    //Single source breadth first search
    public BreadthFirstDirectedPaths(Digraph G, int s)
    {
        _marked = new Boolean[G.V()]; //create a boolean array for all vertices
        _distTo = new int[G.V()]; //create a boolean array for all vertices
        _edgeTo = new int[G.V()]; //create a boolean array for all vertices
        //initialize each element of _distTo to Int32.MaxValue
        for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++) _distTo[v] = INFINITY;
        BFS(G, s);
    }

    /*
    * A function to do breadth first search.  In this case we use a for loop rather than a
    * recursive function to find the shortest path from s to v.
    * We start with the source vertex s.  Rather than "fanning out" from each vertex recursively
    * we travel along a single path (in turn) adding connected vertices to the q Queue until
    * all vertices have been reached.
    * We avoid "going backwards" or needlessly looking at all paths by keeping track of 
    * which vertices we've already visited using the _marked[] array.
    * We keep track of how we're moving through the graph (from s to v) using _edgeTo[].
    * We keep track of how far we've traveled using _distTo[w].
    */
    private void BFS(Digraph G, int s)
    {
        /*
            * Helps us keep track of what path to go down.
            * Add each new connected vertex to the end of the 
            * queue.  Once we travel down it
            * remove it from the queue.
            * */
        Queue<Int32> q = new Queue<Int32>();
        _marked[s] = true;
        _distTo[s] = 0;
        q.Enqueue(s);
        while (q.Count > 0)
        {
            int v = q.Dequeue();
            foreach (int w in G.Adj(v))
            {
                if (!_marked[w])
                {
                    _edgeTo[w] = v;
                    _distTo[w] = _distTo[v] + 1;
                    _marked[w] = true;
                    q.Enqueue(w);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    * In the BFS method we've kept track of the shortest path from s to all connected vertices
    * using the _distTo[] array.
    * */
    public int DistTo(int v)
    {
        return _distTo[v];
    }

    /*
    * In the BFS method we've kept track of vertices connected to the source s
    * using the _marked[] array.
    * */
    public Boolean HasPathTo(int v)
    {
        return _marked[v];
    }

    /*
    * We can find the path from s to v working backwards using the _edgeTo array.
    * For example, if we want to find the path from 3 to 0.  We look at _edgeTo[0] which gives us
    * a vertex, say 2.  We then look at _edgeTo[2] and so on until _edgeTo[x] equals 3 (our 
    * source vertex).
    * */
    public IEnumerable<Int32> PathTo(int v)
    {
        if (!HasPathTo(v)) return null;
        Stack path = new Stack();
        int x;
        for (x = v; _distTo[x] != 0; x = _edgeTo[x])
            path.Push(x);
        path.Push(x);
        return path; **Problem is here**
    }
}
```

i find this code from [here](http://www.rkinteractive.com/blogs/SoftwareDevelopment/post/2013/06/25/Algorithms-In-C-Breadth-First-Paths-Of-Directed-Graphs.aspx) `Digraph g = new Digraph(dsayisi);` graph is done. When i try to call bfs class with graph and source vertex. icant get output. when i want  specific destination path for source to destination

```
BreadthFirstDirectedPaths bfs = new BreadthFirstDirectedPaths(g,source-1);
            bfs.HasPathTo(destination - 1);
            var path = bfs.PathTo(destination - 1);
            /*output of path
```

it gives error

```
public IEnumerable<Int32> PathTo(int v)
        {
            if (!HasPathTo(v)) return null;
            Stack path = new Stack();
            int x;
            for (x = v; _distTo[x] != 0; x = _edgeTo[x])
                path.Push(x);
            path.Push(x);
            **return path;**
        }
```

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Stack' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: `BreadthFirstDirectedPaths bfs = new BreadthFirstDirectedPaths(g, source - 1);
            IEnumerable<Int32> path;
            path = bfs.PathTo(destination - 1);
            foreach (var item in path)
            {
                label9.Text += item.ToString();
            }`
IEnumerable<int 32> path thats what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET has two classes called `Stack` - a generic one (i.e. `Stack<T>`) and a non-generic (i.e. the "plain" `Stack` with no `<T>`). Your code uses non-generic stack in the context where you must return `Stack<Int32>`, which creates the problem.

Using

```
var path = new Stack<Int32>();
```

will fix the compile issue, because `Stack<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Still gives error when calling 
var path = new Stack<Int32>();
path = bfs.PathTo(destination - 1);Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`
public IEnumerable<Int32> PathTo(int v)
        {
            if (!HasPathTo(v)) return null;
            Stack<Int32> path = new Stack<Int32>();
            int x;
            for (x = v; _distTo[x] != 0; x = _edgeTo[x])
                path.Push(x);
            path.Push(x);
            return path;
        }
    }`

Comment: @MuratAy I meant you should replace `Stack path = new Stack();` with `var path = new Stack<Int32>();`

Comment: i did replace but still get same error 
`BreadthFirstDirectedPaths bfs = new BreadthFirstDirectedPaths(g, source - 1);
            var path = new Stack<Int32>();
            path = bfs.PathTo(destination - 1);`
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int>'

Comment: ``public IEnumerable<Int32> PathTo(int v)  
        {  
            if (!HasPathTo(v)) return null;  
            var path = new Stack<Int32>();  
            int x;  
            for (x = v; _distTo[x] != 0; x = _edgeTo[x])  
                path.Push(x);  
            path.Push(x);  
            return path;  
        }  
    }``